# Synchronising messages from multiple ZeroMQ publishers

Tags: node.js, message-queue, zeromq

I'm trying to create a stock monitoring application. I have two ZeroMQ publishers running that get the current stock price from two respective services. The first service is the major source of information and no message from the service can be dropped.

I want to combine the two prices into one object and push it to the front-end.
Each message has a timestamp that indicates the time of the observation of the price and is the basis of combining the messages.

However, both the messages do not arrive at the same time and the system has to wait until both the messages have arrived and then combine them and subsequently push them to the front-end.

I have been able to get it working using an in-memory map that stores the messages indexed by timestamp and checks if both the messages have arrived. If they haven't, it waits for a certain time before sending the messages. The message delivery is expected to be in order and the data from the first service cannot be dropped.

```
const messageQueue = new Map();

monitoringServiceOne.on('message', function (topic, message) {
   synchroniseMessages(topic, message);
});

monitoringServiceTwo.on('message', function (topic, message) {
   synchroniseMessages(topic, message);
});

function synchroniseMessages(topicName, incomingMessage) {

    if (topicName == "ServiceOne") {
        const message = messageQueue.get(message.time);

        // If message exists, it means service two message has been received
        if (message) {
            pushToFE({ ... { message }, "ServiceOne": incomingMessage })
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const message = messageQueue.get(message.time);
                if (message) {
                    pushToFE({ ... { message }, "ServiceOne": incomingMessage })
                }
            }, DELAY)
        }
        messageQueue.set(message.time, { "ServiceOne": incomingMessage });
    } else {
        const message = messageQueue.get(message.time);

        // If message exists, it means service one message has been received
        if (message) {
            pushToFE({ ... { message }, "ServiceTwo": incomingMessage })
        } else {
            messageQueue.set(message.time, { "ServiceTwo": incomingMessage });
        }
    }

}
```

Even though this is working, I feel like reinventing the wheel. Are there any existing ZeroMQ paradigms or patterns that I can use to improve the code? I have been looking for an event-driven pattern that allows me just define the logic for the sink.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there's nothing in ZMQ that'll do that for you. It's an actor model system, and all it does is guarantee that whole messages will turn up in the order they were sent machine to machine. There are no timing guarantees.

For example, if there is a PUB / SUB setup and there are two or more PUBlishers (an allowed combo I think), the time order in which messages are PUBlished by different PUBlishers does not necessarily result in them arriving in that order in the SUBscriber. But it does guarantee that multiple messages sent by any one of those PUBlishers won't get swapped around in transit.

So, if your ServiceOne and ServiceTwo were PUBlishers on the same ZMQ socket, you could not be confident of getting messages in the order 1a, 2a, 1b, 2b, 1c, 2c, 1d, 2d, 1e, 2e, 1f, 2f, 1g, 2g. They could arrive as 1a, 2a, 1b, 1c, 2b, 2c, 2d, 1d, 2e, 1e, 1f, 2f, 1g, 2g. The numbers need not be in order, but the letters for any one given number will be.

I like the idea of using a map (a dictionary? My node.js knowledge is very limited...), elegant. Presumably, you'd have to have something to prune the map now and then, e.g. if ServiceOne got disconnected for a while the map could get quite large.

Er, is it supposed to be `incomingMessage.time` that's used in the call to `messageQueue.get()`, so `messageQueue.get(incomingMessage.time)`, and similar for the `messageQueue.set()`?